# Populated Dropdown with autoComplete textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angular js . I want to make a page with two dropdowns .One for country and other for cities .I want to make filter dropdown 2 according to the country selected.And i want to autocomplete my textbox by place depending on the selection of dropdown 2 (i mean city  dropdown).
can anyone help me please???

Comment: what have you done so far?researched ?

Comment: well  i have my auto complete textbox but i am facing problem to fit the code in existing java script .Can u tell me how to make textbox autocomplete by city .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to select country and based on selected country you need to display cities list in other dropdown right? Here is my code.
**Html template code**

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>CitiCountry</h2>
    <div ng-controller="CitiCountry">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-6  col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchcountry" ng-  options="co.country for co in countryList |orderBy:'country'">
          <option value="">Select Country</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchCity" ng-options="ci.city for ci in citiesList | filter:searchcountry | orderBy:'city'">
         <option value="">Select City</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS code**

```
function CitiCountry($scope) {
$scope.countryList=[{"country":"Pakistan"},{"country":"India"}]
    $scope.citiesList=[{"city":"mumbai","country":"India"},
                       {"city":"banglore","country":"India"},
                       {"city":"Islamabad","country":"Pakistan"},
                       {"city":"Delhi","country":"India"}];
    $scope.$watch('searchcountry', function() {
        $scope.searchState = null;
    });
    $scope.$watch('searchState', function() {
        $scope.searchCity = null;

    });
}
```

Here is fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbespusp/)

Comment: @AshishKumar If it is worked for you, please mark my answer.